# Vertical align div in zurb foundation for apps

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, flexbox

In foundation for apps, there is the new flexbox system to display elements.
I can't figure out how to vertical align a grid-content in a grid-block.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 7):

I found the v-align css when looking into foundation code:

```
<div class="grid-block v-align">
  <div class="grid-content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```